# Get a column value from different table without PK/FK relation in Spring Data - JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have a Entity class named as Employee

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "employee")
    @DynamicUpdate
    public class Employee {

        private String empId;
        private String name;
        private String employeeDefaultCountry;

        @Id
        @Column(name="emp_id", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true, length=8)
        public String getEmpId() {
            return empId;
        }

        public void setEmpId(String empId) {
            this.empId= empId;
        }
        ...
    }
```

employeeDefaultCountry is defined in other table "system_defaults" and there is no primary and foreign key relation between these two tables(employee and system_defaults).
However a constant value will be provided for system_defaults id(PK) that is constant 1. How can i achieve it?

Achieving via Native SQL:

```
select empId,name,(select employee_default_country from system_defaults where id=1) as DefaultCountry from employee.
```

Output:

```
empId,Name,DefaultCountry
101,Ahmed,India
103,Parkash,India
...
```

I want to achieve this in JPA.

Note: This DefaultCountry field should be readable, when saving to DB it should not write.

```
employee Table fields(emp_id(VARCHAR2),name(VARCHAR2)) only two fields

system_parameters Table fields(id(INT),default_country(VARCHAR2),default_designation(VARCHAR2)) only three fields.
```

Entity of System_defaults:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "system_defaults")
@DynamicUpdate
public class SystemDefaults {


    Integer id;
    String defaultCountry;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "default_country", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, length = 40)
    public String getDefaultCountry() {
        return defaultCountry;
    }
    public void setDefaultCountry(String defaultCountry) {
        this.defaultCountry = defaultCountry;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried using @SecondaryTable but it require pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Comment: so there is no entity that maps to this other table? if not then forget it, you can't

Comment: Oh come on there must be a way.I am new in JPA but there must be an aternative.

Comment: I am not getting what is your entity.but If you are asking about entity class yes I do have separate entity class for both.

Comment: It is simple just wanted to add in employee result set, an additional  column value from different table and that column value will be of single row repeated in each record. as you can see in SQL query.

Comment: If you have an entity that maps on to this "system_defaults" table then PUT IT IN YOUR QUESTION!

Comment: table detail and entity of system_default added.